# How to prevent resolve in angular2 router?

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Is there any way to prevent resolve on router if only parameters on that router are changed?

For example, I have this route config.

```
{path:'home/:status', component:HomeComponent,pathMatch:'full',resolve:{ actionList : HomeActionListResolve}}
```

The `resolve` here returns full data set and the component just needs to filter the data based on `status` like (active, completed, etc)parameter.

What i am trying to achieve is that, if the user is landing on this URL for first time, then `resolve` should be called, so that it can fetch data.

But if user is changing only `status`, then `resolve` should not be called OR even if it is called, then it should not make HTTP request to get the same data again and again.

Can someone please suggest a way to achieve this?

Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: are you saving the status info somewhere in service

Comment: @RahulSingh, No I am not storing. It will be appended in the URL itself and component will retrieve it and set it a property for usage.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Injectable()
export class ResolveFactory implements Resolve<any> {

  url: string[];

  constructor() {

  }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any>|Promise<any>|any {
    // get the snapshot from activatedroutesnapshot
    let urlStatus= route.url[0].path; 
    or
    let urlStatus = state.url; 

    if(url.contains(split url to get the status){
         return false;
      } else {
        do your work call service and add the status to the URL[] in Resolve
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: So you suggesting not to make HTTP calls if there is status in URL and return false. Am i right ??

Comment: @SameerK you can do what ever you want there nd after each service call or in else add the status to the url array

Comment: Thanks, but the moment i inject `Route` into the resolve, i get the following error `TS24220: class 'HomeActionListResolve' incorrectly implements the interface 'Resolve<any>'. Types of property 'resolve' are incompatible. Type '(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot, router: Route) => any' is not assignable to type '(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot) => any'.`

Comment: please remove the route from the constructor call get the snapshot from activated route snapshot updated the answer my bad

Comment: Now this error `property 'value' does not exist on type 'UrlSegment[]'`  for `let urlStatus= this.route.url.value.map(val => val.path);`.  any idea ??

Comment: try this route.url[0].path the route your we are using is ActivatedRouteSnapshot updating the answer hope it works now